# SQL Parameters in where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I apologize if this is a simple question but I feel like there's something fundamental I'm not understanding.

I have the following script:

```
select @sql = 
    'select
     fld1
    ,' + @param1 +'
    ,fld2
from
    table
where
    column = ''y'''
exec (@sql)
```

which returns exactly the results I'd expect, but when I change the column in the where clause to a parameter as below:

```
select @sql = 
    'select
     fld1
    ,' + @param1 +'
    ,fld2
from
    table
where
    @param2 = ''y'''
exec (@sql)
```

no results are returned at all.  Is there a fundamental reason I can't use a parameter in the where clause like this?

Thanks

Comment: Do you see how you have used `@param1` differently than `@param2`?    Why did you do that?

Answer (score 5):

Learn to use [`sp_executesql`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) and to pass parameters into the query execution.

This looks like:

```
select @sql = '
select fld1, @param1, fld2
from table
where @param2 = ''y''
';

exec sp_executesql @sql, N'@param1 ?, @param2 varchar(255)', @param1=@param1, @param2=@param2;
```

The `?` for the type of `@param1`.

Comment: Importantly, this method allows the plan cache to keep just one plan to cover all parameters. The previous methods, if called frequently, could fill up the cache and push out useful plans.

Answer (score 0):

After the where clause, a column name is expected.And in your case, it just provides a column value, which is the reason why the expected result is not obtained.

```
     SELECT
      -- Stuff
     FROM Sale
     WHERE SaleDate BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate
```

This is the usual format followed when local variables(here @startDate and @endDate) are used with where clause.

```
 set @param2=''y'''
 select @sql = 
'select
 fld1
,' + @param1 +'
 ,fld2
 from
 table
 where
 column=@param2
 exec (@sql)
```

So it should be like this.

Answer (score 0):

**Also**, You can do it in your way just need some changes as below and I hope `@param1` and `@param2` are string variable otherwise we need to cast it to `varchar`

```
SET @sql = '
    SELECT
        fld1,
        ''' + @param1 + ''' as param1,
        fld2
    FROM
        TABLE
    WHERE ''' + @param2 + ''' = ''y'''

EXEC (@sql)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the parameters are object names (columns), maybe you should try doing it as with `@param1`.

```
select @sql = 
    'select
     fld1
    ,' + quotename(@param1) +'
    ,fld2
from
    table
where
    ' + quotename(@param2) + '= ''y'''
exec (@sql)
```

(The use of `quotename()` avoids trouble with "special" names.)

Otherwise you'd have `@param2` literally in your query text.